# VMware encryption library issue

Tags: encryption, virtual-machine, vmware

Recently because of a error my Windows unexpectingly restarted.
I was using a virtual machine at that time, and after the restart the configuration file went missing (.vmx) I managed to rebuild this file using the vmware log.

After this, I wanted to start the machine again but it gives a error.

> "Could not open virtual machine: /path/pc.vmx Encryption libraries
>   problem."

I have used the Encryption function in vmware to encrypt the machine.
At this point I cant find any answers to fix this problem, I have the decryption key etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is document from [Workstation 11 Documentation Center](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-11/index.jsp#com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-FFE84F7C-0B48-4090-9D0E-CB925097735E.html). Hope it can help.

> **Remove Encryption from a Virtual Machine**
>     You can remove encryption from a virtual machine.
>
> Prerequisites
>
> ■ Power off the virtual machine.
>
> ■ Remove any sensitive information from the virtual machine.
>
> Procedure
>
> 1 Select the virtual machine and select VM > Settings.
>
> 2 On the Options tab, select Encryption.
>
> 3 Click Remove Encryption.
>
> 4 Type the encryption password.
>
> 5 Click Remove Encryption.

Comment: Not sure how to do this or if I even can. I forgot the mention I am using Vmware workstation 11

Comment: Thanks for this guide, but the problem is even more complicated, I can't open the virtual machine at all. when I try to add the machine to my library I get the error I mentioned.

Comment: That's a difficult case and I'm sorry for being unable to provide further information.